# Geographic crime profiling in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

How would you implement [geographic profiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_profiling) in QGIS?

There doesn't seem to be any pre-existing plugins and my Python skills are not quite good enough to implement it myself. Specifically, [Rossmo's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rossmo%27s_formula) would be a good contender for creating an accurate crime profile map.

Comment: I don't think you'll have much luck with that, the formula is patented thus any software implementing it would need to  be licensed (therefore not free) or subject to litigation. Probably the closest you're going to get to it is 'hot spot' analysis http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/creating_heatmaps.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use [CrimeStat](http://nij.gov/topics/technology/maps/pages/crimestat-downloads.aspx) as a standalone app - it has "journey to crime" analysis, which uses similar methods to Rossmo's Rigel program. The output could then be pulled into QGIS for visualisation.